# Date change issue in Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I am trying to change date but Firefox browser is giving me error. However the same code works fine in Chrome browser.

Here's the code in my controller:

```
$scope.dateFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy";

$scope.change = function($event, selected) {
    var selectedchange = moment(selected).format('DD-MMM-YYYY')
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Not able to save it to database. If I use $scope.dateFormat = "dd/mmm/yyyy" then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox follows `dd/mm/yyyy` format. Looks like firefox has some issues with - in date format. Change the date format from `dd-mm-YYYY` to `dd/mm/yyyy`